# How to change a UITextView's input after a certain timeline? E.g. Every 24 hours? swift

Tags: ios, swift, time, uitextfield

Does anyone know which method to use in order to set a UITextView's input to change automatically every 24 hours?
I have a long array of strings and I just want the textView to show a new item in this array every 24 hours.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Like, how is the array stored?  What should happens after all strings in the array are consumed?

Comment: I was thinking it as simple as possible. Just storing the array inside the ViewController's class as a let-constant, and when the array run's out, it would just start over.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have

```
var arr = ["con1","con2","con3"]
```

Then when you opened the app

```
if let date2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "date") as? Date {
   var time = Date().timeIntervalSince(date2)
   var res = Int(time.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:86400))! // 86400 = 24hrs * 60 * 60
   if res < arr.count {
      textView.text = arr[res]
    }  
}
else {
  // first open
  textView.text = arr.first!
  UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(),forKey:"date")
}
```

Comment: This won't work correctly on days that don't have 86400 seconds in them.

Comment: Hey. I see the logic behind your codes. I do have some issues with it though. Maybe it's just me being stupid, but I don't understand why you are reaching the array's strings to the textfield by writing: arr[res] ?
And xCode also has a problem with this part of the code

Comment: I'm talking about your date math. It has nothing to do with the array size. It's probably more appropriate to use `Calendar` to get the difference in days between the two dates than it is to compare the number of seconds against 86400. Not all days have 86400 seconds in them.

Comment: As far as i know it's for a month not a day   who has 30 / 31 / 28 but a day is 24hrs never met any other 23 / 25 hrs a day

Comment: Maybe they don't have day light saving time where you live.